# How to limit and adjust the maximized form inside the splitcontainer in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I was wondering how can I limit the movement of the window just inside the split container?

Also when the form is maximized, how can it automatically resize when the split container is adjusted that it will not go under the second panel?

The forms are all child form.

[Image that the window form can go under the split](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EFwE.jpg)

[Image of the maximized window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4GR3.jpg)

[Image when the split is adjust](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y73qL.jpg)

Comment: There is only one sensible way to address this, set the form's FormBorderStyle property to None.  Setting its Dock property to Fill tends to be sensible next.

Comment: that will make my forms unmovable and unresizable. inside the splitcontainer, there can be more than 1 form.

Comment: You are going to have to write a lot more code to make these forms behave themselves.  Google "windows forms docking library" first.

Comment: does docking also applies even if the form is not maximized?

Comment: Hmya, the term "maximized" just doesn't mean anything anymore when you embed a form as a child control.  I did mention the Dock property intentionally, setting it to Fill would be the rough equivalent to "maximized".  You have some sort of custom windowing model in mind, but what it should look like is not obvious from the question at all.

Comment: umm. i cant do dock fill. since there can be more than 1 forms inside the split container.

Comment: Sure, and if you maximize a normal window then there will be more than 1 window underneath it.  You'll surely want to think about this for a while.

Comment: the user can still restore down. i just want the forms to stay inside the splitcontainer and dont hide underneath it.